# angular ui-sref params not equal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I have this code:

```
<a ui-sref="contacts({ type: contact.type })">Joe</a>
```

Which says "get the contacts that type = contact.type.  So in the url I would pass a param contacts/friends and it would give me a list of contacts with type "friends"

is there any way that I can say this: "get the contacts that type != contact.type"

meaning, if i pass a param contacts/friends to show results with all contacts that do not have type "friends"

I've tried several variations of this:

```
<a ui-sref="contacts({ type != contact.type })">Joe</a>
```

with no result.

does anyone know if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

`ui-sref` should not be used to pass params to the state. use `stateParams` to do this.

Comment: but i need a link.  how would i do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Check http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider - the `stateConfig.params` allows you to pass any value to the new state.

Answer (score 0):

Params are there to pass data, not to do database query.

If you want to get all contacts that are not of type A, make a REST request/DB query or whatever way you use to fetch data, and use the recieved 'type' param as part of it. for example:

SELECT * FROM contacts where Type != {type}